# Python Pandas Dataframe - consider only first occurrence in column [Combined Decision]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, for these 2 columns, [Decision_A], [Combined_Decision], is there a way that I only take first occurrence of [Combined_Decision] == TRUE while subsequent "TRUE" can be ignored until next "TRUE" appears in [Decision_A] in pandas dataframe?

Dataframe columns be like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over all of the rows while checking for the appropriate conditions.  Use some sort of flag to maintain whether there has been a `True` in the first column since the last desired result.

The following self-contained example should achieve roughly what you want, putting a `1` in the `desired_result` column if conditions are met.  The way I implemented it, if there are `True` values in both cells of the same row, this yields a desired result.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Decision_A': [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False],
                   'Combined_Decision': [True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, True]})

A_flag = False
df['desired_result'] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Decision_A'] == True:
        A_flag = True
    if A_flag == True and row['Combined_Decision'] == True:
        A_flag = False
        df.loc[i, 'desired_result'] = 1

print(df)
```

gives

```
   Decision_A  Combined_Decision  desired_result
0       False               True               0
1       False              False               0
2       False              False               0
3        True              False               0
4       False               True               1
5       False              False               0
6        True               True               1
7       False               True               0
8       False               True               0
```

P.S. Making [good reproducible examples for pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) will likely get you answers more quickly here.

Comment: i sincerely appreciate your guidance on this! thank you! this solves my issue. thank you again. (i shall practice giving more context, code when posting question in future.)